# C# Deserialize string of multiple arrays with json-string in it explicit to List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing

i have a json-string, or bit more something like a "string of arrays":

```
"[  
   {  
      "type":"radio-group",
      "label":"Radio-Button-Gruppe",
      "name":"radio-group-1556028993486",
      "className":"iCheck",
      "values":[  
         {  
            "label":"aaaaaaa",
            "value":"aaaaaaa"
         },
         {  
            "label":"bbbbbbbbb",
            "value":"bbbbbbbbb"
         },
         {  
            "label":"cccccccccccc",
            "value":"cccccccccccc"
         }
      ]
   }
],
[  
   ...
],
[  
   {  
      "type":"header",
      "label":"Überschrift"
   }
]"
```

Now I want to have a `List<string>` of each array in this string. Something like:

```
List<string> x[0] = "{  
          "type":"radio-group",
          "label":"Radio-Button-Gruppe",
          "name":"radio-group-1556028993486",
          "className":"iCheck",
          "values":[  
             {  
                "label":"aaaaaaa",
                "value":"aaaaaaa"
             },
             {  
                "label":"bbbbbbbbb",
                "value":"bbbbbbbbb"
             },
             {  
                "label":"cccccccccccc",
                "value":"cccccccccccc"
             }
          ]
       }"
```

What's the best way to do that?

I already tried out `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>()` but my problem is that he wants to deserialize my jsons to an object. But I want to keep them as a string und put them to my list.

Why I need a list of string for each array?
Because I use the json-strings inside the arrays to render a form. each array show you a page of the form, and the json is the data for rendering this form.
to render this form i have to go through a loop through all of this arrays and render the json in it for every page.

Comment: Simplest path would be to deserialize to an object, then get the data you want and serialize each back to JSON. Not sure why you want the strings in a list though, as you could always serialize back to a string at any time you need to persist the data or send it someplace.

Comment: Deserialize it into an object and then do whatever you need such as making it a "string". I am not sure what you mean by *keep them as a string* because it is not a string. This statement makes no sense either: "string of arrays"

Comment: I need the complete JSON of each array as data. The JSON will be used in a FormBuilder to render my form. And because this form has tabs, each array describes a page of it.I have to go through all of this arrays in a loop to render my form.

Comment: I can't deserialize it to a List<string>-object as I needed, because he doesn't want to deserialize everything between the "{" "}" brackets to a simple string.

Comment: First of all, you have a malformed JSON. I guess you need an array of objects, not multiple arrays with a single object.

Comment: @BohdanStupak don't see it as a json, more like a string of multiple arrays with json-strings as data. i have to parse the arrays to an list of string. this behavior is intended.

Comment: I believe then it's easier for you to write a custom parser that will search for matching square brackets and put each item between them into your collection. Just beware that regex (which you may consider as an option for that task) consumes a lot of resources for long strings.

Comment: @BohdanStupak okay, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JToken>>(json)` where `json` is each of your top level arrays. Then you can iterate through the results and use `.ToString()` on each JToken object.

As others have pointed out, you don't have valid JSON, so I didn't try to give a solution to parse out the top level arrays.

```
var json = @"[  
   {
      ""type"":""radio-group"",
      ""label"":""Radio-Button-Gruppe"",
      ""name"":""radio-group-1556028993486"",
      ""className"":""iCheck"",
      ""values"":[
         {  
            ""label"":""aaaaaaa"",
            ""value"":""aaaaaaa""
         },
         {
            ""label"":""bbbbbbbbb"",
            ""value"":""bbbbbbbbb""
         },
         {
            ""label"":""cccccccccccc"",
            ""value"":""cccccccccccc""
         }
      ]
   }
]";
var arrays = new[] { json };

var objectsAsStrings = new List<string>();
foreach (var array in arrays)
{
    var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JToken>>(array);

    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        objectsAsStrings.Add(token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hell yes, that's perfect. Thank you, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = "yourjson"; 

var jsonnew = "[" + json+ "]";

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonnew);

var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
  var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
   result.Add(str);
}
```

You can use this , too.